# SQL error in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to change a field in my users table to a varchar of 200.  Currently it is 60 and not long enough.  I tried using ->change() but because the table has an enum I get an error `Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.` 
As a result I am trying to change the column using a raw sql statement. 
Here is the line I am trying to use.

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users CHANGE COLUMN subrole VARCHAR(200)');
```

When I try this I get an error

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                   
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the   
  right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(200)' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE users CHANGE COLUMN subrole VARCHAR(200))
```

What do I need to change?  I am trying to change the column of subrole to size varchar 200.

Answer (score 3):

could be you need  MODIFY

```
 DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN subrole VARCHAR(200)');
```

Answer (score 1):

`CHANGE` is meant more for renaming columns and changing the definition:

```
CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition
    [FIRST|AFTER col_name]
```

You want `MODIFY` to change just the definition:

```
MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
    [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
```

[MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-column)